# Evento Click, pegar o valor do input da linha de forma dinâmico

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-eventos, eventos

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo

```
<body>
   <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='item'>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <input type="hidden" value="0">
  </tr>
  <tr class='item'>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <input type="hidden" value="1">
  </tr>
</table>
  </body>
<Script> 
   $(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
    console.log(this);
    $(this).remove();   
   });
</script>
```

Quero pegar o valor do input invisível ou até mesmo de alguma determinada coluna. O evento click que fiz eu consigo pegar todo o elemento TR e elementos filhos, porem não consigo acessar um dado em especifico pelo *This*. Alguém consegue me ajudar, se consigo pegar o valor do input que vem no *This*?

Answer (score 1):

```
<Script> 
$(document).on('click', '.item', function(){
 console.log($(this).children('input[type=hidden]')[0].attributes.value); 
});
```

o comando children('input')[0] vai procurar pelo primeiro input com type hidden e attributes.value vai selecionar o atributo value
espero ter ajudado

Comment: Também consigo filtrar por qual outra tag ne?

Comment: claro. Só precisa trocar a tag e o seletor 'input'. Se quiser pode até escolher mais de uma tag separando por virgula dentro da tag, por exemplo 'input, div'. Recomendo você pesquisar mais sobre seletores no jquery